# Iterating through a collection of objects

Tags: c#, linq

### Subject

I have to iterate through a collection of objects (in this case `IGrouping<string, SupplyDemand>`). So I could do this easyly using a query with LINQ.

### Code

```
    public IEnumerable<string> getParentPegs(IGrouping<string, SupplyDemand> data)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> query =
            from d in data
            where d.Source.ToLower() == "make"
            select d.Part;

        return query;
    }
```

### Problem

I'm using this function inside a loop in a VSTO Excel project and it's pretty slow, besides it stops running (memory leak). So I came up with the following code:

### Improved Code

```
    public List<string> getParentPegs(IGrouping<string, SupplyDemand> data)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        var enumerator = data.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            SupplyDemand obj = enumerator.Current;
            if (obj.Source.ToLower() == "make")
            {
                result.Add(obj.Peg);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

### Question

Is there any other way to improve this?

Comment: How are you using the getParentPegs method? The original code returns a lazily evaluated expression and not an actual collection, so if in your code you do this:

`var pegs = getParentPegs(....);
int count = pegs.Count();
foreach(var peg in pegs){ 
  // Doing something else here
}`

Will cause your expression to be evaluated twice, whereas the improved code will only evaluate it once.  You can overcome this by forcing it to evaluate and store it in a list by calling the .ToList() method:

var pegs = getParentPegs(...).ToList();

Or return a List within getParentPegs.

Comment: Makotosan; I'm using it inside a loop, that's what I've been trying to optimize (archiving all parent pegs for a component). Yes, you're right about evaluating the expression twice, so I came up with the second code. So mainly, this question is about the linq performance against a simple iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same with just a `foreach` loop instead of reading the enumerator.

You can use the `String.Compare` method to do a case insensetive compare instead of creating a lowercase version of each string that you compare.

Improved improved code:

```
public List<string> getParentPegs(IGrouping<string, SupplyDemand> data) {

  List<string> result = new List<string>();

  foreach (SupplyDemand obj in data) {
    if (String.Compare(obj.Source, "make", true) == 0) {
      result.Add(obj.Peg);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Note: In your first code you are getting the property `Part`, but in the second you are getting the property `Peg` instead.

Answer (score 2):

how about this :

```
 public IEnumerable<string> GetParentPegs(IGrouping<string, SupplyDemand> data)
    {
        foreach(var d in data)
             if(d.Source.ToLower() == "make") yield return d.Part;

    }
```

Comment: Excellent!, But how come that this is faster than my second example?

Comment: It actually does the same thing but it's a bit more readable in my opinion

Comment: It might be faster if you are not evaluating the result of `GetParentPegs` immediately, since the loop in `GetParentPegs` will only be executed when the `IEnumerable<string>` is enumerated.